# XSLT Accessing value of element from another variable outside a for-each

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My requirement is quite ridiculous. My apologies!
I am a victim of such obnoxious requirements!

Source XML:

```
<Order>
    <OrderLines>
        <orderline><!-- Items may be repeated but with different instructions -->
            <id>100</id>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <instruction>Instruction one</instruction>
        </orderline>
        <orderline>
            <id>100</id>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <instruction>Instruction two</instruction>
        </orderline>
        <orderline>
            <id>101</id>
            <quantity>2</quantity>
            <instruction>Some text</instruction>
        </orderline>
    </OrderLines>
</Order>
```

**Source Two(Can be accessed with $Order/PODetail)**

```
<PODetails>
    <Intro>
        <seqno>001</seqno>
        <text>Sometext</text>
    </Intro>
    <item> <!--Items will not be repeated -->
        <seqno>002</seqno>
        <id>100</id>
        <name>COAL</name>
        <Supplier>123</Supplier>
    </item>
    <details>
        <seqno>003</seqno>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <unitprice>150</unitprice>
    </details>
    <item>
        <seqno>004</seqno>
        <id>101</id>
        <name>MICA</name>
        <Supplier>123</Supplier>
    </item>
    <details>
        <seqno>005</seqno>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <unitprice>160</unitprice>
    </details>
    <Summary>
        <seqno>006</seqno>
        <text>Sometext</text>
    </Summary>
</PODetails>
```

**Output XML:**

```
<PODetails>
    <Intro>
        <seqno>001</seqno>
        <text>Sometext</text>
    </Intro>
    <item>
        <seqno>002</seqno>
        <id>100</id>
        <name>COAL</name>
        <Supplier>123</Supplier>
        <instruction>Instruction one</instruction ><!--From source one-->
    </item>
    <details>
        <seqno>003</seqno>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <unitprice>150</unitprice>
    </details>
    <item>
        <seqno>004</seqno>
        <id>100</id>
        <name>COAL</name>
        <Supplier>123</Supplier>
        <instruction>Instruction two</instruction >
    </item>
    <details>
        <seqno>005</seqno>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <unitprice>150</unitprice>
    </details>
    <item>
        <seqno>006</seqno>
        <id>101</id>
        <name>MICA</name>
        <Supplier>123</Supplier>
        <instruction>some text<instruction>
    </item>
    <details>
        <seqno>007</seqno>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <unitprice>160</unitprice>
    </details>
    <Summary>
        <seqno>008</seqno>
        <text>Sometext</text>
    </Summary>
</PODetails>
```

**Explanation**

1. The `item` and  `quantity` in source one take precedence(even though o/p takes the structure of  source two).
   *Reason:*
   The item in source one will be available in source two. A difference is that the quantity is summed up for a particular quantity in source two. *Find item 100's quantity summed up to 2  in source two.*
   The reason being source one may contain different `instruction` for the same item, thus it has to be treated seperately. However, other details like `unitprice` of these items are the same which are included from source two. For example, the item coal has different instructions and they have to included twice in the output. However, other details like   `unitprice` are the same which are to be fetched from source two.
2. `seqno` is just an incremental number for every first level siblings of the root element wiz., `intro`, `item`, `detail`, `summary`…
3. Challenge I am facing is to access the elements of source two when I loop through every `<orderline>` of source one.

***Clarification***
I am a noob when comes to xslt. But,even with all my noobness I infer that the `<item>` `<details>` should be enclosed with something like `<items>`, but I cant change the xsd as it is associated with other systems. Is it even possible to access **Source Two variable** when I loop through every `<orderline>`. With some initial research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921208/accessing-variables-outside-of-for-each-in-xslt) I infer it is not possible. Is there a work around?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand.... "Source Two" and "output" are the same????

Comment: Oh crap! My bad.! I will edit the question in sometime. Thank you for spotting it.

Comment: You can post the XSL-T you have already tried at the same time :)

Comment: How do you relate elements in one document to elements in the other, by the `id` element, by the position, or how exactly?

Comment: Yes, the id element will be referral point. Same `id` may occur more than once in the first document, whereas it will not repeat in the second document.

Comment: Please select XSLT 1.0 **or** XSLT 2.0, not both.

Comment: @martin. Made changes to the tags.

Comment: I don't think your output matches your input. If it does, then you need to explain the logic. Why does the second orderline produce an item with segno 004? And which quantity takes precedence?

Comment: If the match is on `id` and your first sample posted has `id`s `100` and `103` while the second sample has an `id` `101`, why are `103` and `101` merged (with `<name>MICA</name>` and `<instruction>some text<instruction>`) in your result sample?

Comment: @martin. Thanks. My sincerest apologizes. Its a typo. Both are 101. A bad cut copy amongst 1000 odd items that I have. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand parts of your explanation esp. this one:

> A difference is that the quantity is summed up for a particular
>   quantity in source two. *Find item 100's quantity summed up to 2 in
>   source two.*

Assuming that the output should have exactly one `item` (and one accompanying `details` node) for each `orderline` in the source document - IOW, that there is no need to group the orderlines by their id and sum up their quantities - I would suggest the following approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="lookup-doc" select="document('source2.xml')" />

<xsl:key name="item" match="item" use="id" />

<xsl:template match="/Order">
    <PODetails>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$lookup-doc/PODetails/Intro"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="OrderLines/orderline"/>
        <Summary>
            <seqno><xsl:value-of select="format-number(2 * count(OrderLines/orderline) + 2, '000')"/></seqno>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$lookup-doc/PODetails/Summary/text"/>
        </Summary>
    </PODetails>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="orderline">
    <xsl:variable name="orderline" select="." />
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="id" />
    <xsl:variable name="number" select="2 * position()" />
    <!-- switch context to lookup document -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$lookup-doc">
        <xsl:variable name="item" select="key('item', $id)" />
        <item>
            <seqno><xsl:value-of select="format-number($number, '000')"/></seqno>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$id | $item/name | $item/Supplier | $orderline/instruction"/>
        </item>
        <details>
            <seqno><xsl:value-of select="format-number($number + 1, '000')"/></seqno>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$orderline/quantity"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$item/following-sibling::details[1]/unitprice"/>
        </details>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the following assumptions:

1. Your current node is an `orderline`, either via `template match="orderline"` or `for-each select="orderline"`
2. The $Order variable is in scope and XPath-able (you have both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 tagged, so we don't know that for sure).

You would then be looking at an XPath something like this to access, say, `unitprice`:

```
<xsl:value-of
    select="$Order/PODetails/item[id = current()/id]
    /following-sibling::details[1]/unitprice"/>
```

Adjustments may need to be made based on the nature of the $Order variable.  Also, I typed this on the fly, so haven't tested for typos on my part.